# WebSphere class having http listen port value

Tags: class, websphere, port

I need to know WebSphere's class which holds the WebSphere's http listen port value.
Can any one help me with this.

Its similar to WebLogic post

http://www.coderanch.com/t/536941/BEA-Weblogic/Class-holds-weblogic-port#2463378

I want to find the http listen port, using reflection when the class(which holds port configuration) loads by class loader.

Answer (score 0):

The http listen port can be found / configured in the `[was_home]/profiles/[profile_name]/config/cells/[cell_name]/nodes/[node_name]/serverindex.xml` file.